# Combine two lists of tuples by key

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists of two elements tuples. First element of tuple is ID and second is some kind of value. Type of value depends on list.

```
lst1 = [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3) ]
lst2 = [ ('b', 5), ('a', 4), ('c', 6) ]
```

What is the easiest way to combine them into:

```
lst3 = [ ('a', 1, 4), ('b', 2, 5), ('c', 3, 6)]
```

Comment: You really need to use a dictionary here.  Why aren't you?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if these were dicts instead of lists of tuples. Is there a reason they aren't? (And, if there _is_ a reason, presumably it has something to do with either key order or duplicate keys, so... how do you determine the order in `lst3`, and what should happen if there are duplicates?)

Comment: Anyway, even if these do need to be lists, the simplest solution is to make a temporary `dct2 = dict(lst2)`; then you can, e.g., `lst3 = [(key, value, dct2[key]) for key, value in lst1]`.

Comment: I have to get ID, first value and second value of lst3 sorted by 1st element, and then again ID, first value, second value of lst3 sorted by 2nd element (counting from 0).

Comment: Yes, it shoud. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you turn those lists of tuples into dictionaries first. Then, assuming that both lists contain the same "keys", you can use a simple list comprehension to get the respective values from the two dictionaries.

```
lst1 = [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3) ]
lst2 = [ ('b', 5), ('a', 4), ('c', 6) ] 
dict1 = dict(lst1)
dict2 = dict(lst2)
lst3 = [(k, dict1[k], dict2[k]) for k in sorted(dict1)]
```

Note that dictionaries have no fixed order. If you want to preserve the order the keys had in `lst1`, you might also use this, as suggested in comments:

```
lst3 = [(k, v, dict2[k]) for k, v in lst1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3) ]
lst2 = [ ('b', 5), ('a', 4), ('c', 6) ] 

dst1 = dict(lst1)
dst2 = dict(lst2)

for i in dst1:
    if i in dst2:
        dst1[i] = (dst1[i],dst2[i])

print dst1
{'a': (1, 4), 'c': (3, 6), 'b': (2, 5)}
```

Then you can this format `dst1` to whatever format you want the result in.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create one dict using the first element from each tuple from lst1 as the key and storing the tuple as the value, then iterate over the second list and add the last element to the corresponding tuple in the dict.

```
lst1 = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
lst2 = [('b', 5), ('a', 4), ('c', 6)]
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(zip((tup[0] for tup in lst1), lst1))

for k,v  in lst2:
    d[k] = d[k] + (v,)
print(d.values())
[('a', 1, 4), ('b', 2, 5), ('c', 3, 6)]
```